# How to get checkbox value from list view ... which is connected to Sqlite data base?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Help to get mobile number and get it in a edittext... i am gone...

help me to get the check box value and take the mobile number to some where. to send sms using Sms manager
Class name adapter... which contains row of the list view.

```
List list=new ArrayList();
Context context;



public Adapter(Context context, int resource)
{
    super(context, resource);
    this.context=context;
}


public void add(Product object) {
    list.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    final Holder holder;
    if (row==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlist,parent,false);
        holder =new Holder();
        holder.id=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tsnoo);
        holder.name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tname);
        holder.birth=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tbirth);
        holder.email=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.temail);
        holder.req=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.treq);
        holder.mobile=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tmobile);
        holder.check=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.tcheck);
         row.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder= (Holder) row.getTag();
    }

    Product product= (Product) getItem(position);
    holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(product.getId()));
    holder.name.setText(product.getName().toString());
    holder.birth.setText(product.getBirth().toString());
    holder.email.setText(product.getEmail().toString());
    holder.req.setText(product.getReq().toString());
    holder.mobile.setText(product.getMobile().toString());
    holder.check.setChecked(false);
    holder .check.setChecked(itemChecked[position]);

    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            itemChecked[position]=isChecked;

        }
    });

    return row;
}
private boolean[] itemChecked;
private void createCheckedHolder() {
    itemChecked = new boolean[getCount()];
}
static class Holder{
    TextView name,birth,email,req,mobile,id;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

}

I have used AsyncTask to to Synchronize it...

Comment: I am not going to read through that much code trying to understand it when you have not told me what it’s supposed to do. If you cannot narrow down your problem, I’m afraid we cannot help you. Also, what research have you done? So that I somebody trying to help isn’t just repeating what you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i made my answer my self... with a simple meathod...

```
holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(holder.check.isChecked()){
            View get=null;
            for (int i=0;i<getCount();i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    get = getView(i, get, listView1);
                    holder.mobile = (TextView) get.findViewById(R.id.tmobile);
                    String last = holder.mobile.getText().toString();
                    String[] data;

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), last, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            }
            else
            {

            }


        }
    });
```